# Is there any way to add a pause after so many iterations in a php foreach loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to update post meta for over 100,000 WooCommerce products (using ACF's update_field function). The code is pretty straightforward, it assigns a priority order based on the menu order of an attribute. Since it's going through so many products, the memory limit gets reached. Is there maybe a way to pause for a few seconds after every 1,000 records so that the memory limit doesn't get exhausted?

```
  $args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'pa_brand',
    'hide_empty' => false,
  );
  $brands = get_terms("pa_brand");
  $brand_IDs = array();
  foreach ($brands as $brand) {
    array_push($brand_IDs, $brand->term_id);
  }




  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
  );
  $products = get_posts($args);

  // This is the foreach loop that goes through thousands of products
  foreach ($products as $prod) {
    $ID = $prod->ID;
    $brand = get_the_terms($ID, 'pa_brand');
    $brand = $brand[0] ?? false;
    if (!$brand) {
      continue;
    }
    $brand_ID = $brand->term_id;
    $priority = array_search($brand_ID, $brand_IDs) + 1;

    update_field("field_61607fa7967c4", $priority, $ID);
  }
```

I've confirmed the code does work properly. I tried on just 5 products.

Comment: Keep a counter and once the counter hits 1,000 `sleep()` and then reset the counter

Comment: There's an X/Y Problem here: if your problem is *running out of memory*, then *pausing the processing* won't make any difference. No memory is going to be freed up while PHP is sleeping. Probably your _actual_ problem is that you are "leaking" memory somewhere - keeping references in memory to data that you've actually finished with.

Answer (score 1):

For this job, you shouldn't use the get posts function because it grabs all fields from the database and all that you want is the id and the brands.

Try to fetch the database directly:

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE 
post_type='product'", OBJECT );
foreach ($results as $prod) {
  //...
}
```

Not really sure about the field for type in the posts table. Maybe you have to look for the correct name.

Comment: Is that faster than using 'fields' => 'ids' in the get_posts args?